# C#. BouncyCastle. Ошибка при шифровании данных с использованием ГОСТ3410

Tags: c#, шифрование, криптография, гост

Есть задача зашифровать данные (envelope) с помощью сертификата с алгоритмом ГОСТ3410.

Мой метод:

```
private byte[] EnvelopeData(byte[] data, X509Certificate certificate)
{
    try
    {                          
        var generator = new CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator();
        generator.AddKeyTransRecipient(certificate);

        var envelopedData = generator.Generate(new CmsProcessableByteArray(data), CmsEnvelopedGenerator.DesEde3Cbc);
        return envelopedData.GetEncoded();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Получаю исключение:

> Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsException: can't find key generation algorithm. ---> Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecurityUtilityException: Cipher 1.2.643.2.2.19 not recognised. in Org.BouncyCastle.Security.CipherUtilities.GetCipher(String algorithm) ...

Выполнив отладку по исходникам BouncyCastle, пришел к выводу, что исключение генерируется на этапе шифрования сессионного ключа, а именно - при поиске алгоритма шифрования 1.2.643.2.2.19.

Фрагмент метода `GetCipher()` с либы `BC` [CipherUtilites.cs]:

```
try
{
    cipherAlgorithm = (CipherAlgorithm)Enums.GetEnumValue(typeof(CipherAlgorithm), algorithmName);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    throw new SecurityUtilityException("Cipher " + algorithm + " not recognised.");
}

switch (cipherAlgorithm)
{
    case CipherAlgorithm.AES:
        blockCipher = new AesFastEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.ARC4:
        streamCipher = new RC4Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.BLOWFISH:
        blockCipher = new BlowfishEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.CAMELLIA:
        blockCipher = new CamelliaEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.CAST5:
        blockCipher = new Cast5Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.CAST6:
        blockCipher = new Cast6Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.DES:
        blockCipher = new DesEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.DESEDE:
        blockCipher = new DesEdeEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.ELGAMAL:
        asymBlockCipher = new ElGamalEngine();                  
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.GOST28147:
        blockCipher = new Gost28147Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.HC128:
        streamCipher = new HC128Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.HC256:
        streamCipher = new HC256Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.IDEA:
        blockCipher = new IdeaEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.NOEKEON:
        blockCipher = new NoekeonEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4:
    case CipherAlgorithm.PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4:
        streamCipher = new RC4Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.RC2:
        blockCipher = new RC2Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.RC5:
        blockCipher = new RC532Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.RC5_64:
        blockCipher = new RC564Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.RC6:
        blockCipher = new RC6Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.RIJNDAEL:
        blockCipher = new RijndaelEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.RSA:
        asymBlockCipher = new RsaBlindedEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.SALSA20:
        streamCipher = new Salsa20Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.SEED:
        blockCipher = new SeedEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.SERPENT:
        blockCipher = new SerpentEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.SKIPJACK:
        blockCipher = new SkipjackEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.TEA:
        blockCipher = new TeaEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.THREEFISH_256:
        blockCipher = new ThreefishEngine(ThreefishEngine.BLOCKSIZE_256);
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.THREEFISH_512:
        blockCipher = new ThreefishEngine(ThreefishEngine.BLOCKSIZE_512);
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.THREEFISH_1024:
        blockCipher = new ThreefishEngine(ThreefishEngine.BLOCKSIZE_1024);
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.TNEPRES:
        blockCipher = new TnepresEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.TWOFISH:
        blockCipher = new TwofishEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.VMPC:
        streamCipher = new VmpcEngine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.VMPC_KSA3:
        streamCipher = new VmpcKsa3Engine();
        break;
    case CipherAlgorithm.XTEA:
        blockCipher = new XteaEngine();
        break;
    default:
        throw new SecurityUtilityException("Cipher " + algorithm + " not recognised.");
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.
Возможно есть другие решения для *Windows* для шифрования данных таким способом.

Comment: Хм, а откуда взялось имя `1.2.643.2.2.19`?

Comment: С сертификата, который применяется для шифрования сессионного ключа.

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно, криптопровайдера для 1.2.643.2.2.19 на машине не установлено. Как вариант - КриптоПро, ну и стоит прочесть https://habrahabr.ru/post/134037/

Comment: Загружаю сертификат и приватный ключ с файлов, а не путем получения через криптопровайдер
Скорее всего, в BouncyCastle не реализовано асимметричное шифрование через ГОСТ34-10

Comment: Не понял - [криптопровайдер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80) это модуль, реализующий соответствующие алгоритмы. В самом BouncyCastle может быть ниего не реализовано, он может общаться с криптопровайдерами через CryptoAPI. Какие криптопровайдеры установлены на машине - такие он и может. " Как вариант - КриптоПро".

Comment: BouncyCastle не использует CryptoAPI - всё нативное, в т.ч. реализация алгоритмов.

Comment: Не то, чтобы совсем - местами System.Security.Cryptography встречается, хотя Вы правее, все нативное. Но тут какая-то нестыковка - 1.2.643.2.2.19 это действительно ГОСТ Р 34-10.2001, но он для цифровой подписи. В BouncyCastle он есть (поиск по ECGost3410) и используется в CMSSignedDataGenerator (в отличие от CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator) как раз для подписания.